# Javascript Classes with Cordova is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, ecmascript-6

I'm using JS classes in `Cordova` application like:
`

```
class CustomerController {
    constructor() { 
        this.cs = new CustomerServices();
        this.customerModelObj = new CustomerModel();

    } 
 }
```

Then, I called the `customerController.js` as `<script src="customerController.js"></script> in my`index.html`. Then I instantiated the class

```
`try{ 
var customerObj = new CustomerController()
}catch(error){
 alert(error);
}`
```

I'm getting an error which is `CustomerController is undefined` when I build and run the android app.

What I have tried also, I used the `crosswalk` plugin to replace the original webview as I read it's by chromium and supporting new JS features with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded Cordova to the latest version, created a new project, migrated my project files to the new project and installed [ionic-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-p%E2%80%A6) plugin. Worked like a charm!

You might face some UI issues and need to put some efforts on it.